# Sum of factorials mod p

Tags: math, optimization

I was wondering what the fastest way to compute the sum of the factorials from 1! to n!, mod a prime p, would be. My current code just keeps a running factorial, and then mods it after each multiplication. Here's my code:

```
ans = 1

fact = 1
for i in range(1, n+1):
    fact *= i
    fact %= mod
    ans += fact
    ans %= mod
```

mod is the prime number to be modded against, fact is a running calculation of the factorial, and ans will have the final answer. I found various algorithms to calculate the factorial of a number mod p, but not the sum of factorials. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: For small modulo value you can limit loop, because all factorials `>= mod!` are divisible by `mod`: `for i in range(1, min(mod, n+1)):`

Comment: Your routine looks pretty good and is only linear in execution time. You should use Mbo's suggestion to greatly improve speed for large `p`. You might save a very small amount of time by combining lines: `fact = fact * i % mod` and `ans = (ans + fact) % mod`. If you execute this routine often you could memoize its results (store them in a list or dictionary).